# How to call a onClick Javascript function with Parameters via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

i'm trying to *echo* the following function add() in HTML

```
'<a onclick="add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].')" href="javascript:void(0)">'
```

The function is not getting invoked. How should i implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
echo '<a onclick="add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].')" href="javascript:void(0)">';
```

will gives you

```
<a onclick="add(a,b)" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

You need to add single quotes if you are passing strings to your function, like this

```
echo '<a onclick="add(\''.$row["x"].'\',\''.$row["y"].'\')" href="javascript:void(0)">';
```

Then in your document you will get

```
<a onclick="add('a','b')" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'<a href="javascript:add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].')">'
```

OR

```
'<a onclick="add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].')" href="#">'
```

Or

```
'<a onclick="add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].') return false" href="#">'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this.

**Php File**

```
<?php
     echo '<a onclick="add('.$row["x"].','.$row["y"].')" >Onclick Function</a>';
 ?>
```

**.html file**

```
<a onclick="add(<?= $row["x"] ?>,<?= $row["y"] ?>)" href="javascript:void(0)">Onclick Function</a>
```